# Iterations for rows 1-100 of if cell A1 = 0, then 0, else goalseek cell B1 value by setting to C1 value

Tags: string, excel, vba

I have written some code to goalseek the value in one cell (U) against value in another (V) but by changing the value in a third (Q).
It first does a check against another cell (Y) which is an error check cell.
All on the same row.

I want to run it for all rows in a range,
I have written the following:

```
If Sheets("Main").Range("Y16") <> "Volumes OK" Then 
Sheets("Main").Range("Q16").Value = 0
  Else
Sheets("Main").Range("U16").GoalSeek Goal:=Sheets("Main").Range("V16"), ChangingCell:=Range("Q16")
  End If
```

What I want to do is try to use the string function to iterate for rows 16-200 but am not sure how many integers I need to define and in what order and how to get it to work!
I think I have to dim string and then use For loops but not sure how...

Answer (score 0):

To loop over rows 16 to 200, do this:

```
Dim MyRow as Integer

for MyRow = 16 to 200
  If Sheets("Main").Range("Y" & MyRow) <> "Volumes OK" Then 
    Sheets("Main").Range("Q" & MyRow).Value = 0
  Else
    Sheets("Main").Range("U" & MyRow).GoalSeek _
         Goal:=Sheets("Main").Range("V" & MyRow), ChangingCell:=Sheets("Main").Range("Q" & MyRow)
  End If
Next
```

If any of your values need to come from a fixed location, replace the dymanic `.Range("x") & MyRow)` to a fixed `.Range("xy")` so that it points to a consistent column `x` and row `y`.

**Note**: In the `GoalSeek` formula, I changed `Range()` to `Sheets("Main").Range()` to remain consistent with the rest of the formula. If, for some reason, you were to modify this code in the future and move away from `Sheets("Main")`, then `Range()` (without the leading `.`) would point to the then current worksheet, which is probably *not* what you would want. By specifying which sheet it's from, you can move around wherever you want and still have the line of code work. By explicitly stating which sheet you're working on, it's also much more readable.